# Grails Google Maps - Render map as index it can't pick up the places saved in db

Tags: grails, maps

I have successfully followed the [Google Maps example at IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails05208/index.html). The map is currently located at: localhost:8080/myapp/trip/map and I want to move the map to be as the index page, localhost:8080/myapp.

I can easily render the map if I replace the code in index.gsp, but the points in the db are missing. It seems that the array of points (lat and lng) are not following / are empty because I'm outside the trip views.

Do I have to make the array in my trip controller which holds the points global? And how do I do that? Or is there another way, I think it's a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation for [URL mappings](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/single.html#6.4.3%20Mapping%20to%20Views).
Just edit *grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy*

Change following

```
  "/"(view:"/index")
```

to

```
  "/"(controller:"trip", action:"map")
```